# Xamarin forms determine when a view has been drawn to screen

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to determine when a view is visible on the users screen (Android), but I seem unable to find any event that is raised to indicate this. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Because of differences between the platforms, there is no cross-platform event that occurs *after* the view is shown to user. Could write custom renderers for a specific type of view, to implement this. Would need to override view drawing, and have a flag that is set the first time a view is drawn. A cheap hack is in `ContentPage.OnAppearing`, start a MainThread task that delays 200 - 500 ms, then does something. Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that the page is actually visible yet. What exactly do you want to do once it is visible?

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for this event on the page/view itself, you can override the `OnAppearing` function. This function is fired immediately before the page is visible to the user.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms

I understand that you asked for an event that occurs *after* the page is visible. Have you tried `OnAppearing`? If so, are you able to provide some more information about why it was not useful to you?

**Example: MyPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
   public MyPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
      base.OnAppearing();
      // Your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: a core rule of SO is that code and errors should never be posted as images.  Please edit your answer to include the code as properly formatted text, not an image

Comment: *"immediately before"* isn't *"view is visible"*. It would have been better to put a comment on the question, asking if "immediately before" would be useful to the question-asker. If they said yes, then its worth an answer.